# Can multiple azure function read from single partition on event hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Can multiple azure functions read from single partition on event hub. Can they scale up more then number of partitions in event hub?

Comment: Do you mean multiple instances of the same function or really multiple functions?

Comment: Multiple instances of same function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Let's say your Event Hub has `N` partitions. Function might be running on `M` instances (servers). Each partition will be locked by one of the servers, i.e. two servers won't concurrently process messages from the same partition. `M <= N` will hold.

Each server may run multiple function executions in parallel. They can be from multiple partitions, but also the server might process several events from the same batch from the same partition at the same time.

The simplest experiment which shows that:

- 1 partition in Event Hub
- Azure Function which sleeps for 10 seconds for each event
- Send 10 events to the hub at the same time

In the logs you will see that they were processed in parallel, not sequentially.

Comment: Does this hold true in Computational model as well? Since we don't have control on internal nodes, but functions instances (in count) can be more than partitions?

Comment: To my knowledge, this applies to Consumption plan too, if that's what you mean

Comment: This is not correct.  Outside of ownership rebalancing during scaling or host issues, there is no concept of parallel processing for a partition, whether in single-dispatch or multi-dispatch.  The trigger will always dispatch once for a partition and wait for processing (and checkpointing, if needed) to complete before dispatching more events from the same partition.    More context can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670877/159548

Comment: Amending to mention that I do not know if the original answer was point-in-time correct in 2017, but it has not been since at least 2019.